# Why is my HP laptop showing "System Fan (90B)" error even after cleaning the fan with compressed air?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, temperature, hp-pavilion

I am using HP Pavilion DV6-6b51ea laptop. The laptop is 6 years old. For the last 1 month, the fan was running loud (even loud now may be) and since the last 2 weeks, I have been getting `System Fan (90B)`  error sometimes. Some days ago, I bought a can of compressed air and blew air inside the laptop vents (without opening the laptop). Still after this, I am getting the same error sometimes. [p.s:- 5 months ago, a laptop repair guy disassembled my laptop and cleaned the dust in the fan and changed the thermal pastes]

Why am I getting the same error still?

[image]

[image: Screenshot from Speedfan software]

Comment: https://support.hp.com/rs-en/document/c03620929

Comment: because the fan is likely dying, not because it is dirty. Fans have a specific lifespan, and at 6 years old, your laptop has lived longer than the manufacturer expected it to be in service.

Comment: the fan still runs, even after the error...Everything is going ok I think. But the fan is creating more noise than usual. Now the fan speed is 1785 RPM according to speefan software..,,

Comment: fans slow and get louder as they deteriorate. for a low diameter fan like one in a laptop, 1785 is pretty low. the laptop has probably reduced output unless you are heating up, so I'd be curious what the peak CPU is once the laptop exceeds 70C. if it doesn't spin up a good bit more, it really is time to consider replacement. Moving parts always go first, as they are killing themselves every second they are alive, so Fans and HDDs have a pretty fixed lifespan for a given usecase.

Comment: please see the screenshot from Speedfan software (i attached with the question)

Comment: the fastest fan speed i experienced is 4080-4180 RPM

Comment: is there anybody?

Comment: There are various possible factors that could effect this. It's nice that you did append a screenshot. What happens under actual load? At what point did you see those speeds and what were the temps? I'm not sure about the RPM range, depending on the diameter of the fan 4000 rpm might also be bogus.

Answer (score 0):

The fan is dying. Replace it yourself or pay someone nerdy to do it for you. I wouldn't recommend running it much, if at all, until this problem is fixed since you could be overheating tiny sensitive laptop components.
Here are instructions to DIY, if you are so inclined!

HP kindly provides service manuals which can instruct you on how to replace parts. You can buy replacement parts cheap on ebay with the part numbers in the service guide.

From searching for "DV6-6b51ea service manual" I found the service manual for you here: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03015537.pdf

Comment: Kyle is right, the error you are getting on the bios is that your fan didn't spin up to the set  threshold during the POST check.

Comment: there is no problem in using the laptop. But the error comes sometimes, and if I press enter, then everything goes like normal. I don't know what is happening really.

Comment: so the fan still runs? even so, that error means needs replaced asap

Comment: the fan still runs, even after the error...Everything is going ok I think. But the fan is creating more noise than usual. Now the fan speed is 1785 RPM according to `speefan` software....

Comment: Why did someone -1? Always a stupid critic/perfectionist on this site...

Comment: I'd guess it was -1'd because of the advert.